# How do browsers process multiple javascript tags?

Tags: javascript, browser

Does a browser process these two snippets the same way?:

```
    <script type="javascript">
     myFunction1();
     myFunction2();
    </script>
```

Vs.

```
<script type="javascript">
 myFunction1();
</script>
<script type="javascript">
 myFunction2();
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try it for yourself to see the output? Yes, they should be equivalent.

Comment: @Alec: there could potentially be nuances to this that are not obvious if you don't already know them so as to know exactly what experiments to set up and what to look for. While I agree that the answer is plainly yes, I think this is a very valid question. There could potentially be an answer such as "oh, script blocks execute in parallel threads, so if there's a lot of heavy processing going on in one block, you can't really be sure that `myFunction1` will be called before `myFunction2`" - now this is not the case, of course, but I'm just trying to prove a point =)

Answer (score 3):

They will be absolutely equivalent. There are no scope differences, no execution differences, nothing.

The only difference is that there will be two instead of one `script` element in the parsed DOM.